# Are there any scope that escape all special characters in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I have a set of queries with randoms data that i want to insert in database. Randoms data may have any special characters.
for example:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('!^'"twco\dq');
```

Are there any scope that escape all special characters?

please help.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written, could you improve the wording to make it easier to understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no "scope" in MySQL to automatically escape all special characters.

If you have a text file containing statements that were created with potentially unsafe "random values" like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('!^'"twco\dq');
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're basically screwed. MySQL can't unscramble a scrambled egg. There's no "mode" that makes MySQL work with a statement like that.

Fortunately, that particular statement will throw an error. More tragic would be some nefariously random data,

```
x'); DROP TABLE students; --
```

if that random string got incorporated into your SQL text without being escaped, the result would be:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('x'); DROP TABLE students; --');
```

---

The escaping of special characters has to be done *before* the values are incorporated into SQL text.

You'd need to take your random string value:

```
!^'"twco\dq
```

And run it through a function that performs the necessary escaping to make that value safe for including that as part of the the SQL statement.

MySQL provides the `real_escape_string_function` as part of their C library. Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html. This same functionality is exposed through the MySQL Connectors for several languages.

An even better pattern that "escaping" is to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**, so your statement would be a static literal, like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ( ? )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` character to escape special characters like below. See this [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e2f9/1) if in doubt.

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('\!\^\'\"twco\\dq');
```

Per [`MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) documentation, below are the defined escape sequences

```
Table 9.1 Special Character Escape Sequences

\0  An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\'  A single quote (“'”) character.
\"  A double quote (“"”) character.
\b  A backspace character.
\n  A newline (linefeed) character.
\r  A carriage return character.
\t  A tab character.
\Z  ASCII 26 (Control+Z). See note following the table.
\\  A backslash (“\”) character.
\%  A “%” character. See note following the table.
\_  A “_” character. See note following the table.
```